# Completion Handler Causes Deinit To Not Be Called

Tags: swift, completionhandler

I have a network task that contains a completion handler, allowing me to determine if and when the task completed successfully;

```
func performUpload(url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (_ response: Bool) -> ()) {
    photoSave.savePhotoRemote(assetURL: url) { response in
        completionHandler(response)
    }
}
```

I call this function from another UIView, by using the following;

```
UploadHelper.shared.performUpload(url: fileAssetPath) { response in
    if response {
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

What I am noticing is that when I capture the *response* and *do stuff*, the class that called this function will never deinit.  However, if I change my function to the following;

```
UploadHelper.shared.performUpload(url: fileAssetPath) { response in }
```

and don't do anything with the response, the class will deinit.

What am I doing wrong with my function?  I would like to capture the response accordingly, but not at the expense of my class not being released from memory.

Comment: By the way, while using `[weak self]` obviously solves the problem, the fact that you’re having a cycle at all is likely caused by `savePhotoRemote` saving the closure in some property. In the spirit of defensive programming, if you ever save closures in properties, you might also want to make sure to `nil` that closure property after calling the closure (assuming you no longer need it, as would appear to be the case here). This isn’t in lieu of `[weak self]`, but just a good habit to avoid persistent strong reference cycles at all.

Comment: Thanks, @Rob!  That is very helpful advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a retain cycle. Break it. Change

```
UploadHelper.shared.performUpload(url: fileAssetPath) { response in
    if response {
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

to

```
UploadHelper.shared.performUpload(url: fileAssetPath) { [unowned self] response in
    if response {
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense and has successfully resolved my issue.  Thank you!